# how to pass parameters to ember component

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

This ember component template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/blog-post">
  <h1>Component: {{title}}</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</script>
```

This is the component code:

```
App.BlogPostComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    // how can i access the title property here? (this.title doesn't work)
    // also this.get('title') throws error: undefined is not a function
    computedProp: 'width' + this.title
});
```

And it's usage:

`{{blog-post title=title body=body}}`

I can access the title property from the component template easily with `{{title}}`.

How can i access the `title` property from within the component code, `App.BlogPostComponent`.

Also is there an easy way to ember properties in handlebars such as:

`<h1 style="width: {{percent}}%">`

**Edit**:

When I do this as suggested:

```
App.BlogPostComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  computedProp: function () {
    return 'width' + this.get('title');
  }.property('title')
});
```

I get the error:

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Attributes must be numbers, 
strings or booleans, not function () {
            return 'width:' + 50 + '%';
        }
```

Edit2: Ok the reason for the error is omitting `.property('title')` at the end of function definition. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.get` should work just fine, the problem is that you are not calling it in object context. The correct way to define computed property would be:

```
App.BlogPostComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  computedProp: function () {
    return 'width' + this.get('title');
  }.property('title')
});
```

Things like `<h1 style="width: {{percent}}%">` are impossible right now, you should use `bind-attr` helper + computed property for that.